# Combining UNION, count(*) and rowid in SQL, aka determine blocks used by 2 tables

Tags: sql, count, union, oracle12c, rowid

I have 2 tables MOTHER and CHILD. I want to determine how many blocks they use together. 
Code I usually use to determine this for just one table

```
select count(count(dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid))) 
from MOTHER group by dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid);
```

but since I need both tables and they might be using the same blocks I tried experimenting. So I read that UNION might solve this but I have problems using it according to the tutorials

```
select tem.dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid), count(*) from
(select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) from MOTHER 
union
select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) from CHILD ) AS tem
group by dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid);
```

it doesn't work and shows an error at the `AS tem` part. It says syntax error.
message:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 58

Comment: @Parfait - why would a MOTHER and a CHILD table have the same structure? They almost never do. You do understand, I suppose, that the OP meant "mother" and "child" in the technical sense - the CHILD table has a foreign key pointing to the primary key in MOTHER, right? Absolutely no reason why in general the tables would have the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the query.

The first one, which causes the immediate error, is the keyword `AS`. In Oracle (different from other database products, from what I understand), the keyword `AS` is optional for column aliases, and **prohibited** for table/subquery aliases. Delete the word `AS` before the alias `tem` and that error is fixed.

Then, in the outer select you still want to select from `dbms_rowid` - but that is not possible, you already gave an alias to the subquery, so you can only select from it, not from the tables referenced in the two branches of `union`.

Here is one way to correct it:

```
select   rowid_block_number, count(*) as cnt    -- DON'T USE THIS QUERY! (SEE BELOW)
from     
         ( 
           select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) as rowid_block_number from MOTHER 
           union
           select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) from CHILD
         )
group by rowid_block_number
;
```

Notice that I did away with the alias for the subquery - it is not needed. Also, I gave an alias to the column resulting from the application of `rowid_block_number(rowid)` - you can't call it as is in the outer query.

Now, this is syntactically correct, but the logic is non-existent. For your first count, I have no idea why you group by, and select counts twice. You should simply

```
select count(distinct dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid)) as block_count
from   MOTHER;
```

and if you must do this for two different tables:

```
select count(distinct rowid_block_number) as block_count
from   
       ( 
         select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) as rowid_block_number from MOTHER
         union all
         select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) from CHILD
       )
;
```

or, if you will use `union` instead of `union all`, that will already eliminate duplicates, so just `select count(rowid_block_number)` from the subquery. (That is: you do need some form of "distinct", but you only need it once. Either count distinct in the outer query, or use `union` as you were doing, instead of `union all`, in the subquery, but then you don't need "distinct" in the outer query.)